# Typescript nullable callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I'm trying to create a class which allows passing a callback to alter the side-effects of a method. If you don't pass a callback, then the method will be called directly. This is a basic example:

```js
class Button<T = void> {
    private clickWrapper?: (click: Function) => T

    private _click() {
        // do the click here
        return null;
    }

    constructor(clickWrapper?: (click: Function) => T) {
        this.clickWrapper = clickWrapper;
    }

    public click() {
        if (this.clickWrapper) {
            return this.clickWrapper(this._click.bind(this));
        } else {
            return this._click();
        }
    }

}


class Foo {

    public doStuff() {
        console.log('hello');
    }

}



const button = new Button<Foo>(click => {
    // do some stuff
    click();
    return new Foo();
});

const foo = button.click();
foo.doStuff();


const button2 = new Button();
button2.click();
```

This works, but `foo.doStuff()` complains that foo may be null - even though in this case I provided a clickWrapper, so the return value of `button.click()` cannot be null, it must be an instance of Foo. Is there a better way to define this?

The second issue is I have to copy the Button constructor's parameter type when I've already declared it for Button.clickWrapper. How do I avoid having to declare the type on the private property and constructor parameter?

Comment: You seem to have posted only part of your code, as you reference a bar object and a doSomething method when there are none in the code provided (i only see foo and doStuff)

Comment: That was a typo - the code is correct, I just referenced the wrong thing. I meant `foo.doStuff()`

Answer (score 1):

I have updated you code snippet:

```
class Button<T = null> {
  constructor(private clickWrapper?: (click: Function) => T) {}

  private _click() {
    // do the click here
    return null;
  }

  public click(): T {
    if (this.clickWrapper) {
      return this.clickWrapper(this._click.bind(this));
    } else {
      return this._click();
    }
  }
}

class Foo {
  public doStuff() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

const button = new Button<Foo>(click => {
  // do some stuff
  click();
  return new Foo();
});

const foo = button.click();
foo.doStuff();

const button2 = new Button();
button2.click();
```

Two things:

- TypeScript can't be sure what is exact return type of your `public click` function so it assumes `T | null`, since default `_click` function returns `null`
- To avoid redeclaring types for constructor and property of an object, you can always use shorthand syntax for `constructor assignment` (just add `private` or `public` keyword to constructor param)

Comment: Awesome! This works, but complains that `return this._click();` (void cannot be assigned to type T) which I don't understand because I thought we defined the default of T to be void...

Comment: This depends on your `tsconfig`, but in general you shouldn't be creating `void` type variables. Void actually means no type, so it's semantically wrong. Would be better to change default type of `T` to `null` since that is what is actually assigned in `_click` function.

Void docs:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void

Comment: I suppose I should have left the `return null` out of `_click()` as there won't actually be any return value in the default _click. Is there still a way to get the `return this._click()` line to not complain without turning off `strictNullChecks`? I'm just not clear why void is not allowed when the default value of T is void? Setting T's default to null and leaving the `return null` still has the same problem.

Comment: Sure, just change the return type of `click()` function to `T | void` or `T | null`. But this will require you to check on `foo` before calling it's `doStuff` as it might not be of `Foo` type

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Callback<V> {
  (arg: () => void): V
}

class Button<T = void> {
  constructor(private callback?: Callback<T>) {}

  private onClick = () => {

  }

  public click = () => {
    if (this.callback) {
      return this.callback(this.onClick)
    } else {
      return this.onClick()
    }
  }
}

const button = new Button<number>(
  click => {
    click()
    return 2 +2 
  }
)

console.log(button.click()) // 4
```

I update your code to solve your problems

- Create an interface for the callback type and add the `private callback?` to the constructor to inject the argument to the class
- There are many types for a function, in typescript a function that not return nothing is a `void function`, you are returning null, so that didn't match with your `clickWrapper` type, I assume you aren't gonna return anything from the `click` function so I update that type to match too with a `void function`